# I am trying to send facebook custom app-events in node js using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-analytics, facebook-node-sdk

basically I am doing a post request at  https://graph.facebook.com/{app_id}/activities . As mentioned in [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/).

The event is getting displayed in facebook analytics events dashboard , but the unique Users and count field is getting displayed as 1.(not getting updated with each post request) . Is this the usual behaviour or can someone please help me where I might be going wrong ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is this page useful at all? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/